# How to change master password on AWS RDS without downtime?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

So, if I change the master password on my RDS instance, my application which connects to the instance will be down for a couple of minutes until I change the password in it as well. If I do the other way around and change the password in the app first, then the same thing happens. How can I change the master password without causing any downtime?

Also, I am not sure if changing the password takes effect immediately or not. If not, then it would be better to first change the password of the RDS instance and then when it's ready, change the password in the app....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the application to try to connect with the new password, and if it fails try the old password.

Then change the RDS password.

Once things are working, you can remove the failover code.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't really work in my case because the connection is established during startup and if the connection closes, there isn't any retry mechanism....which leads me to another question: If the connection is succesfull during startup and the password is changed afterwards....does the connection remain still open? If yes, then this would solve my problem indeed.

Comment: Then I think you're stuck with a short downtime while you get both in sync.

Comment: The password is only checked when creating the connection. So open connections are not affected when you change the password.